# Duplicate YII select2 jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, yii, jquery-select2

I use custom theme on my web and it requires `jquery.min.js` so dropdown menu can works, but it seems like `jquery` files was called twice when i use `select2`.

Here are the details.

- When i call jquery on my `main.php`, my dropdown menu works but my select2 doesnt work and got `TypeError: jQuery(...).select2 is not a function` error
- but when i don't call jquery on my main.php, dropdown menu doesnt work and got error like this.

  Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
   bootstrap.min.js:6:37
  ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
   metisMenu.min.js:9:1
  ReferenceError: $ is not defined

How to fix this anyway?

Comment: Can you attach your code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please attach your code here?
Yii has his own build-in jQuery and probably you set on code your own jquery library too. First jQuery library is used for dropdown menu but the second has attached select2 plugin.

You can set mapping on your configuration to exclude Yii build-in jquery plugin or rebuild your code to use build-in jquery plugin for select2 function.

You also need to make sure that you have only one jquery library attached in your end.